# How to autoresize a parent form when a child form resizes in code?

Tags: winforms

When I resize a child form in code, how do I get the parent form to resize automatically to wrap the child form? I have autosize property set to true for the parent form. I called this.MdiParent.PerformLayout() after the size change. I don't want to resize the parent form manually.

Comment: How is that suppose to work in an MDI environment?  The MDI parent is designed to just provide scrollbars if the child form overlaps the boundaries.  Resizing a parent form is not considered great UI — it's usually a jarring experience.

Comment: I am trying to resize the child form to show more content and it's not resizing, I am assuming the parent is constraining it. Why is it jarring? The user would prefer to see all the content instead of resizing the form to see the hidden content.

Comment: But MDI Child forms are floating forms within the MDI area — that's why it doesn't make sense what you are trying to do.

Comment: I guess to confirm, is this an MDI application?  Or are these child "forms" really just child controls?  I think we need to know more about your parent form.

Comment: Yes child form is inside the parent form. The mdi app is not maximized when it starts but the child form needs to be big enough to show all the controls and a grid. Parent form doesn't know how big it needs to be so the child form adjust its size. It doesn't because it can't grow bigger than the parent form. The parent form needs to grow as big as the child needs to be. The child form is controlling the mdi app's size. Just like in a web page where you have a div and the content controls the size of the div. The div, if it doesn't have a fixed width & height, grows to show all the content.

Comment: Why not just `Maximize` the child?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Because it will go as big as its parent. The parent is not big enough. The child controls the size of the parent form/app in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hidden control in the MDI Parent's Control collection that is of a type called MdiClient.  You can use this to help determine how much space is used up by any docked Panels or ToolStrips, then resize the client area of the parent form accordingly:

```
MdiClient mc = this.Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First();
int otherHeight = this.ClientSize.Height - mc.ClientSize.Height;
this.ClientSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width,
                           this.ActiveMdiChild.Height + otherHeight);
```